# How much RAM for Windows?

Tags: windows

On my VPS I run IIS and Apache. I use Apache for a few WordPress blogs and PHP development and IIS for my own .NET development. I have 1 GB of RAM in my hosting plan and I am wondering if it is enough. Access to my site seems a bit on the slower end.

I don't get much traffic, but I am wondering if 1 GB of RAM enough?

I prefer to use Apache and Windows as PHP under IIS is just a configuration nightmare when it comes to file and directory permissions. However, would I expect to see a performance if I just went with IIS instead of running IIS and Apache on the same VPS? Thank you.

**Update - Running Windows Server 2008 R2**

Comment: I fail to see what this being a VPS has to do with anything, it's still Windows, so forget that it's a VPS.

Comment: Which version of Windows? Win 7 or Win 2008 or some other version? 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: This question is as vague as asking what car should I drive...

Comment: @GregD - The red one, obviously.

Comment: Question seems pretty straight forward question to me. Is 1 GB of RAM sufficient to run IIS and Apache on the same machine without performance problems?

Answer (score 1):

It's not going to be an enterprise server? Then don't fuss too much. 1 Gb is a good place to start. You'll obviously keep monitoring it, and if the active memory reaches 100% during normal running of the server then it doesn't have enough.

Answer (score 0):

Extremely vague question, but the answer is "you should try and run stuff and then see if you need to add more ram. Given it is a VPS, that is pretty much a matter of a simple reboot."

I'll add that running PHP on modern versions of IIS is pretty easy. And wasn't really that hard on earlier versions if your windows-fu was strong.

Comment: I would have to disagree with your assessment of PHP on IIS, The permission headaches with WordPress pop up all the time. Trying to do upgrades through WordPress on IIS has always ended being a pain while with Apache it is cake.